# Applying lambda to a new column using an existing column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lambda

Database is rv
columns are 'NextResetDate_rv'(datetime), 'RateResetFreq_rv'(timedelta)
me1 is pd.to_datetime('12/31/2019')

I am trying to create a new column, 'resetcalc1_rv', based on a condition but cant get the code right, could you please point out whats wrong

Basically 'rvresetcalc1_rv' should be equal to 'NextResetDate_rv as long as it falls after 12/31/2019, otherwise 'RateResetFreq_rv' needs to be added to it till the condition is satisfied

```
rv['resetcalc1_rv'] = rv['NextResetDate_rv']

def new1(row):
    while row['resetcalc1_rv'] < me1:
        row['resetcalc1_rv'] = row['NextResetDate_rv'] + row['RateResetFreq_rv']
        if row['resetcalc1_rv'] >= me1:
            break
        row['resetcalc1_rv']

rv['resetcalc1_rv'] = rv.apply(lambda row:new1(row), axis=1)
```

The output right now is 'None' for all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the while loop. Using subtraction and integer division you can find how many units of `'RateResetFreq_rv'` you need to add to each row to satisfy the condition. The `clip(lower=0)` ensures we don't change dates that are already after the specified date. Then you can calculate all values at once.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'NextResetDate_rv': pd.date_range('2019-11-01', periods=8, freq='15D'),
                   'RateResetFreq_rv': pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(31,23,-1), unit='D')})
```

#### Code

```
s = (((pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31') - df['NextResetDate_rv']).dt.days)//df['RateResetFreq_rv'].dt.days).add(1).clip(lower=0)
df['resetcalc1_rv'] = df['NextResetDate_rv'] + s*df['RateResetFreq_rv']
```

#### Output

```
  NextResetDate_rv RateResetFreq_rv resetcalc1_rv
0       2019-11-01          31 days    2020-01-02
1       2019-11-16          30 days    2020-01-15
2       2019-12-01          29 days    2020-01-28
3       2019-12-16          28 days    2020-01-13
4       2019-12-31          27 days    2020-01-27
5       2020-01-15          26 days    2020-01-15
6       2020-01-30          25 days    2020-01-30
7       2020-02-14          24 days    2020-02-14
```

Comment: Hey, RateResetFreq is an existing pre defined column, I cant redefine it

Comment: @LabeebNazim I'm not... You didn't provide sample data so I made some up. Given the existing columns `'NextResetDate_rv'` and `'RateResetFreq_rv'`, I'm only calculating `'resetcalc1_rv'`